# Android: getting thumbnails from specific location on sd card

Tags: android, uri, thumbnails, android-contentresolver

AFAIK accessing thumbnails for images via `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails` would generate thumbnails at first attempt, and that's what I need to perform against specific location on sd card.

The question is how to make valid URI to content under specific folder?

All answers I can find use just `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` as uri to make `managedQuery`. And result of it is Cursor that points to all sdcard images, while none examples can be found on how to access only specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just list files in the directory and parse them to get thumbnails without using content provider. You can use inSampleSize option to get small bitmap not the complete image [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/823966#823966).

Comment: when the size varies very much it would be hard to guess the factor for inSampleSize without loading full image to know it's width and height in order to shrink it to default thumb size (i.e. 90x90)

Comment: You can use justDecodeBound option http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds. It will return you the bitmap size without decompressing the complete image and allocating memory. Knowing image size you can calculate the required inSampeSize factor for each image.

Answer (score 0):

may be is to late, but for some one will be helpfull

[Mihai Fonoage](http://www.blogger.com/profile/10774816347448949131) said...

Use something like

```
File imagesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/pathToDirectory");
File[] imageList = imagesDir.listFiles();
for (File imagePath : imageList) {
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imagePath.toURL().openStream());}
```

[Here you have some great tutorial.](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html)